# Search data and display in an open modal dialog containing the input search field

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-dialog

Hi i have created a function to search and fetch client's data from database based on enter account number in a modal dialog input field and if found displays details in the same dialog box. But if data is found it's not displayed and response for 'no data' is showing as required

Code is as below:-

```
            scope.fetchClientInfo = function() {
                resourceFactory.clientResource.get({clientId: savingaccount.clientId }, function (data) {
                    scope.client = data;
                });
            };

            scope.fetchAccountInfo = function() {
                var searchString = scope.searchText;
                scope.savingaccount = [];
                var searchString = scope.searchText;
                var exactMatch = true;
                resourceFactory.globalSearch.search({query: searchString, resource: "savings", exactMatch: exactMatch}, function (data) {
                    scope.savingaccount = data;
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        fetchClientInfo();
                    } else{
                        Alert('No account found');
                        scope.searchText = "";
                    }
                });
            };
```

HTML

```
         <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divTableBody">
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell">
                        <p class=MsoNormal align=right><span>Account Number:</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divTableCell">
                        <p class=MsoNormalvalue>
                        <input class="form-control1" type="text" name="accountNumber" id="accountNumber" data-ng-model="searchText" required/>

                            <button class="ngdialog-button" ng-click="closeThisDialog()">Search and Display</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

Client information displayed here:-

```
<table class="pretty displayschedule" style="position:relative;bottom:15px;">
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormal align=right><span>CID:</span></p>
        </td>
        <td valign=middle style="width:183px"><p class=MsoNormalvalue><span>{{client.externalId}}</span></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormal align=right><span>Savings Product:</span></p></td>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormalvalue><span>{{savingaccount.productName}}</span></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormal align=right><span>Saving Account Number:</span></p></td>
        <td valign=middle>
            <p class=MsoNormalvalue><span>{{savingaccount.accountNo}}</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormal align=right><span>NID:</span></p></td>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormalvalue><span>{{client.nationalId}}</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormal align=right><span>Address:</span></p></td>
        <td valign=middle><p class=MsoNormalvalue><span >{{client.address}}</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```